# Tweaking animation to make divs appear more frequently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a whack-a-mole style game where the user had to click on the correct number in accordance to a sum above that is randomly generated each time a question is answered. The problem that I am having is that the user sometimes has to wait a long time before the answer they need actually appears, and sometimes it takes around ten second for anything to appear. I need the animation to make the divs appear more frequently but I don't know how to make this happen.

Here is the animation attributes for the number divs

```
function randomFromTo(from, to) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1) + from);
}

function scramble() {
    var children = $('#container').children();
    var randomId = randomFromTo(1, children.length);
    moveRandom("char" + randomId);
}

var currentMoving = [];

function moveRandom(id) {
    // If this one's already animating, skip it
    if ($.inArray(id, currentMoving) !== -1) {
        return;
    }

    // Mark this one as animating
    currentMoving.push(id);

    var cPos = $('#container').offset();
    var cHeight = $('#container').height();
    var cWidth = $('#container').width();
    var bWidth = $('#' + id).width();

    var bHeight = $('#' + id).css('top', '395px').fadeIn(100).animate({
        'top': '-55px'
    }, AnimationSpeed).fadeOut(100);

    maxWidth = cPos.left + cWidth - bWidth;
    minWidth = cPos.left;
    newWidth = randomFromTo(minWidth, maxWidth);

    $('#' + id).css({
        left: newWidth
    }).fadeIn(1000, function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#' + id).fadeOut(1000);

            // Mark this as no longer animating                
            var ix = $.inArray(id, currentMoving);
            if (ix !== -1) {
                currentMoving.splice(ix, 1);
            }
            window.cont++;
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

Can someone show me how to make it so that there is always a set number of answers on the screen at once, rather than having long waiting periods with now numbers?

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/xgDZ4/3/

Comment: *unrelated* I just tested it and lost on the very first question: 14-4. There were no "10" answers. It made me sad :(

Comment: Haha sorry I forgot to mention that "10" is "0" until my graphic designer re-creates the numbers @Nenotlep